# unable to post data to mosquitto broker continuously

Tags: python-2.7, mqtt, raspberry-pi3, mosquitto, paho

I am trying to send data continuously from raspberry pi to a windows pc using MQTT,
I am trying to send 5 data to mosquitto, but the mosquitto seems to get only one value

coding in raspberry pi

```
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
client=mqtt.Client()
client.connect("192.168.0.104",1883,60)
for i in range(0,5):
    data={"protocol":"mqtt"}
    client.publish("/test",str(data))
```

coding at the broker to receive data is

```
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt

print("attempting to connect...")


def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
    if(rc==0):
        print("connection successful broker linked")
    elif(rc==1):
        print("connection refused -  incorrect protocol version")
    elif(rc==2):
        print("connection refused - invalid client identifier")
    elif(rc==3):
        print("connection refused- server unavailable")
    elif(rc==4):
        print("connection refused- bad username or password")
    elif(rc==5):
        print("connection refused- not authorised")
    else:
        print("currently unused")

    client.subscribe("s/test")

def on_message(client, userdata, msg):
    data=eval(msg.payload)
    print(data)

client = mqtt.Client()
client.connect("localhost",1883,60)

client.on_connect = on_connect
client.on_message = on_message
client.loop_forever()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you thought about following the answer I posted here?

https://github.com/eclipse/mosquitto/issues/972

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure the network loop runs for the publishing client as well a the subscriber. The network loop actually handles sending the messages.

The following is the simplest modification to your code.

```
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
client=mqtt.Client()
client.connect("192.168.0.104",1883,60)
for i in range(0,5):
    data={"protocol":"mqtt"}
    client.publish("/test",str(data))
    client.loop()
```